# Dynamically setting div height in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following code in my CSS:

```
div.h120 {
    height: 120px;
}
```

Can it be set **dynamically** so that if I place a class `h150` in a div, it now have **height 150px**?

---

One way to achieve this would be to create a class to every possible height value, but I would like to know if there's a better way.

Thank you for the attention.

Comment: Are you looking for a responsive website? Or are you looking for the user/client to be able to change the div height?

Comment: you cannot achieve this with pure CSS without writing all of it explicitly.  you need to resort to scss/sass or javascript

Comment: Hey @JD333 I made a dashboard in Python Bokeh and I'll send all the chart information to be consumed by the frontend team via json. I would like to send a CSS to adjust some of the charts heights based on the number of categories being displayed. Yes, I want it to be responsive.

Comment: Got it @sertsedat, I'll research it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using scss/sass for this purpose to create functions to generate classes for you:

```css
div{
  @for $j from 1 through 200 {
        &.h#{$j}{
            height: ($j + px);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Got it. The end result would be no different had I hardcoded all the 200 classes, right?
But your way sure is better and I'll research it, thank you.

Comment: Yup it gets preprocessed to a regular css file with the 200 classes which you will bundle alongside your production code. It's just about writing code efficiently and less code to review.